# Авторизация на сайте посредством curl

Tags: curl, php

Авторизируюсь на сайте через cURL записываю куки в файл

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.ini');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.ini');
```

И выполняю некоторые действия. Как лучше всего проверить(кроме чтения cokie.ini и поиска домена где проходит авторизация), созданы куки от сайта или нет, чтобы при каждом действии не проходить по новой авторизацию?

Answer (score 1):

В заголовках посмотреть можно.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак.. При авторизации просто в курле пиши

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.ini');
и курл сам сохраненные куки отошлет вместе с запросом..